# Laravel: office365 connection timeout on aws

Tags: laravel, timeout, office365, connection-timeout

Don't know why smtp.office365.com stopped work suddenly on production but works on dev.
Let's see some code:

.env configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=nao_responda@primorossi.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_SMTPAuth=true
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Grupo Primo Rossi"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=nao_responda@primorossi.com
```

The Laravel error page:

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.office365.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

The weirdest thing is that this configuration worked ok when I published and stopped working for no reason.

Anyone?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
Chenged the port from 25 to 587

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=nao_responda@primorossi.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_SMTPAuth=true
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Grupo Primo Rossi"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=nao_responda@primorossi.com
```

Now it is working good!